# jquery smooth scroll to anchor on another page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to jQuery inside Bootstrap and did a [w3school Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp) to add smooth scrolling to a page. This works fine as long as the anchors are on the same page. I added an imprint and wanted to have the same menu there, so not the links point to anchors on another page (e.g. home.html#section1).
But that does not work at the moment – clicking the links does not have any effect at all.

The script code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
        $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#home']").on('click', function(event) {
            // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
            if (this.hash !== "") {
                // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                event.preventDefault();

                // Store hash
                var hash = this.hash;

                // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                }, 900, function(){

                    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            } // End if
        });

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $(".slideanim").each(function(){
                var pos = $(this).offset().top;

                var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (pos < winTop + 600) {
                    $(this).addClass("slide");
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

When I remove the code snippet from the imprint page, the anchor links are working, but because there is no scrolling, the animated parts of the home.html page do not load (up to the moment I scroll manually, then they will load).
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `e.preventDefault()` assuming you're using only anchor links.

Comment: Thanks, this works the same way as removing the whole script: The anchor link works well now, but on the target site the elements do not load until you scroll manually. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: I'd need to see more code than just your JS. Can you put together a jsfiddle or bootply?